# Firebase Database limiting number of children programmatically

Tags: firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database question:

My app is written to work offline as well (so Persistence is set to true).

There are channels.
A channel can have a max of X subscribers.  This X is stored under Channel details.  Stored alongside is the current no. of subscribers(Y).

In my code, I have a listener(L) that keeps track of X and Y.
When I add/remove a new subscriber, a cloud function transaction increments/decrements Y.  (Alternately my app can start a transaction to update it, but I don't like that option as transactions don't work offline).

The user can add subscribers one after the other quickly (by uploading multiple phone numbers together). At that time I check that Y is less than X.
Unfortunately by the time, the listener (L) gets the current value of Y, my code has the ability to add multiple subscribers.

Consequently, I am unable to restrict the user from adding more that X number of subscribers.
Is there a way to avoid this race condition and stop the user from adding more subscribers than X.

Comment: I think you can do this kind of filtering through Firebase Cloud Function.

Comment: You're going to have some challenges with this in that when the client is offline, it only know about about count that existed when it was last online. It may be better to prevent uploading of data when the client is offline.

Comment: @MosesAprico: Can you be a little bit more specific? Thanks.

Comment: @Jay: Exactly my worry. Good thought on restricting when offline.  Thanks.

Comment: I never use FCM directly myself, but I've watched several videos in youtube about it, and I think it may be able to help you solve your problem. Good luck!